# Implementing SharkyFi/client

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

I am trying to implement SharkyFi/client in an angular application and i was wondering if i can get any help and is putting public key and private key of any wallet would work ?

const cli = new Command()
const options = cli
.requiredOption('--wallet-path ', 'path to private key file')
.parse()
.opts()

const provider = createProvider(options.walletPath)
const sharkyClient = createSharkyClient(provider)
const { program } = sharkyClient

const loans = await sharkyClient.fetchAllLoans({
program,
})
I trying to use this code

Answer (score 0):

If you are gonna just read accounts, you don't even need to provide any keypairs. publicKey in Provider interface is optional for wallet not connected state in general.

Comment: i am trying to read the wallets so i can make loan offers from our website